# how to study for 70-511 TS: Windows Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4

Tags: .net-4.0

I'm trying to get certified for 70-511, but I'm low on resources, since there is no offical Microsoft press materials released, and there is a huge leap between the .NET 4 and the .NET 3.5 version of the exam. The .Net 4.0 version heavily discusses WPF technology.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MCTS 70-511 is a combination of both WPF and WinForms. There existed two different tests for .NET Framework 3.5. There exists books  for both (MCTS-70-505 MCTS-70-502) in Microsoft Press. There are also some free questions at www.testmaster.ch, the questions are in German: http://www.testmaster.ch/MCTS-70-511.test

Hope this helps

Some few question available in English too:
http://www.testmaster.ch/MCTS-70-511-EN.test

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft is planning to release updated materials for this exam, so if you wait for awhile they will be available.

That said, you can get a pretty good idea of what's on the exam by examining [which certifications can be upgraded to it](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/cert-vstudio.aspx#tab2), as well as the [detailed test description](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-511&locale=en-us#tab2).

I've personally found experience to be the best preparation for MS cert exams, so I recommend building a few WPF applications if you haven't already done so. Consider OSS or assisting a local non-profit: you help the community and gain skills that help you.

Answer (score 3):

[MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-511): Windows Application Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627428)

Answer (score 3):

i think the better point of start is review of preparation materials what you can view page of microsoft:

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?ID=70-511#tab3

In this moment can download one test pdf with questions and correct answers, not are real questions for Microsoft certification but is good point of start.

http://www.64bitprogramlar.com/microsoft-70-511-test-training-premium-14979.html

hope you find it useful!
jmdeveloper